# In Gundam Unicorn, when Audrey reveals final coordinate, why does Banagher feel unease

Tags: gundam

In Gundam UC OVA EP 6, Banagher shared the final coordinate with Audrey, which I feel he trusted Audrey to put that into good use. However why is is that at around 27:00 mark, when Audrey revealed the coordinate to everyone, Banagher seems to feel betrayed?

What kind of outcome did Banagher wanted?

Comment: You should at least specify what Gundam series you are referring too, with a hundred out there

Comment: @Mansuro my bad. Added now